# Angular 2 - AOT - Calling function 'ChartModule', function calls not supported

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-highcharts

I am losing my mind and hair over this. I am importing HighCharts in Angular 2 but need to require some of its extra libraries. So far in my code I have

```
import {ChartModule} from 'angular2-highcharts';
@NgModule({
....
imports:[
ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'), require('highcharts/modules/drilldown'))})
]
```

But I keep getting this error

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ChartModule'. function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported fucntion.

So I tried

```
export function highchartsRequire:any {
   return{
     require('highcharts'), 
     require('highcharts/modules/drilldown')
   }
}
...
ChartModule.forRoot(highchartsRequire())
```

Still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Using angular 2
angular cli: 1.0.0-beta.30

**UPDATE - got it partially working thanks to JayChase**

**This works**

```
export function highchartsFactory() {
      return require('highcharts');

    }
```

**But I cannot require two at a time**

```
declare var require: any;
export function highchartsFactory() {
  return function () {
    require('highcharts');
    require('highcharts/modules/drilldown')
  };
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory
    }
  ],
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an issue open for this and a workaround [here](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/160) using an exported function.

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
    import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    declare var require: any;

    export function highchartsFactory() {
      const hc = require('highcharts');
      const dd = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');
      dd(hc);

      return hc;
    }

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ChartModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HighchartsStatic,
          useFactory: highchartsFactory
        }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. If I want to require the drilldown too, do I just add another factory then?

Comment: @Julian I think you should be able to have both the require calls in the one function. I've added the code to the answer.

Comment: any ideas on this Jay?

Comment: @Julian I think I got it working properly, with a lot of help from [this](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/156) GitHub issue. I've updated the answer with the latest code.

Comment: thank you so much!!! I can confirm this works. I really appreciate your help. I mean it

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay : )

Comment: That was amazing, thanks.
I just could not understand what caused the error.