# Calling function 'ChartModule', function calls not supported

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am facing the same issue as described in [Angular 2 - AOT - Calling function 'ChartModule', function calls not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636948/angular-2-aot-calling-function-chartmodule-function-calls-not-supported)

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ChartModule'. function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function.

But in my case, i have 4 require statements and I couldn't get it work the same way the answer has been given for the above question.

I tried like,

```
export function highchartsFactory() {
  const hc = require('highcharts');
  const hm = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  const h3d = require('highcharts/highcharts-3d');
  const sg = require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge');

  hm(hc);
  h3d(hm);
  sg(h3d);

  return hc;
}
```

Could you please point me to what I am doing wrong and how I can solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, by making changes as below by passing highcharts to other modules.

```
export function highchartsFactory() {
  const hc = require('highcharts');
  const hcm = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  const h3d = require('highcharts/highcharts-3d');
  const sg = require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge');
  hcm(hc);
  h3d(hc);
  sg(hc);

  return hc;
}
```